# Does moderate drinking cause damage to the liver?

Tags: alcohol, liver

It's fairly common knowledge that heavy drinking can damage the liver, causing scarring among other issues. Can moderate drinking, say one or two glasses of red wine a day, cause the same damage?

Comment: I'm not an expert but there is some research out there that it may be good to drink moderately, just my 2 cents...

Comment: This is relatively easy to search for everyone, so I won't. According to many studies, moderate alcohol drinking is associated with various health benefits. Even if it is true that a small amount of alcohol can damage individual liver cells, you need to search for final outcomes (proven actual liver disease) to make a conclusion about alcohol toxicity.